# Sometimes moviefile (.mov) sticks on 3.2 ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, movie

I am using MPMoviePlayerController for playing movie in iPad. 
Some times movie gets stuck. 
This happening only in 3.2 iPad.
 
This defects appears randomly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is related to the API - I have this issue on my iPad playing videos a lot. They randomly seem to stop, and I have to press Play to have them resume. It's not a buffering issue, because it happens with local videos too.

I think it's a general iOS bug.